# Probability to get an $8$ on three $8$ sided dice, with $1$ die able to be rerolled

Tags: probability

What is the probability to get an $8$ on three $8$ sided dice, with $1$ die able to be rerolled.
Also, same but with $2$ dice and $4$ dice.

Ty, I'm a bit rusty on my probability math.

Comment: Do you mean "three $8$-sided dice?" Because there is no multiplication going on in that instance, and it is a bad habit to use $\times$ to mean number of instances.

Comment: Sorry, yeah three 8-sided dice

Comment: exactly one $8$ or at least one $8$?

Comment: At least one 8.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The condition that you are allowed to re-roll one of the dice means, in effect, that you are rolling *four* 8-sided dice.

Comment: I had been thinking about exactly that. Makes sense because it doesn't matter what the roll was on the die that is re-rolled because I only need one 8.

Comment: Exactly!  Can you take it from there?

Comment: I think so, if my memory serves me (7 years since I did any probability math) I need to calculate the probability that I get no 8's and then subtract that from 1. Am I right?

Comment: Your memory serves you well.  (I would have just said "Yes" but comments need to have at least 15 characters.)

Comment: 1 - (7/8)^4 = 41,38%   Am I right?

Comment: sorry I typed in 8 first, but then edited the comment

Comment: Thank you very much Barry Cipra, your hint helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to help.  Incidentally, had the problem ask for the probability of getting *exactly* one 8, then the re-roll option would *not* have been equivalent to simply rolling four dice.